# Metamask Connects to Next.js dapp on localhost but not when deployed to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, web3js, vercel

As the title says Metamask automatically connects to the dapp when it loads on localhost, but when I deploy it to Vercel it does not connect:
[working on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE2oQ.jpg);
[not working on vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C58Yz.jpg)

Here is my web3 provider file:

```
import Web3 from "web3"

let web3

if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
  window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
} else {
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9fe88971851d4fb1b8501ed1a22abfbd"
  )
  web3 = new Web3(provider)
}

export default web3
```

This is the top level index.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Card, Button, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import factory from "../ethereum/factory"
import Link from "next/link"

const CampaignIndex = (props) => {
  const renderCampaigns = () => {
    const items = props.campaigns.map((address) => {
      return {
        header: address,
        description: (
          <Link href={`/campaigns/${address}`}>
            <a>View</a>
          </Link>
        ),
        fluid: true,
      }
    })
    return <Card.Group items={items} />
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Segment color="blue">
        <h2>Active Campaigns</h2>
        <Link href="/campaigns/new">
          <a>
            <Button
              floated="right"
              content="Add Campaign"
              icon="add circle"
              labelPosition="left"
              primary
            />
          </a>
        </Link>
        {renderCampaigns()}
      </Segment>
    </Layout>
  )
}

CampaignIndex.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call()
  return { campaigns: campaigns }
}
export default CampaignIndex
```

And this is the contract factory file:

```
import web3 from "./web3"
import CampaignFactory from "./build/CampaignFactory.json"

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  JSON.parse(CampaignFactory.interface),
  //deployed contract address
  "0xBDa369D85732Db4b42b0d04FA5c194460bE39dCC"
)

export default instance
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/tarasshulhan/EthCampaigns). Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very interested in  learning ho to properly deploy a dapp.
Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to make this work? I'm having a very similar issue. On localhost, I can connect correctly. However, when I run the app on production mode `npm run prod` it doesn't work